# Why queue is not multiprocesing safe?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I create some multiprocessing code - very simple to detect problems and I found some problem - queue is not updated with synchronization.

```
# coding=utf-8
import multiprocessing

def do_work(input_queue, output_queue):
  print multiprocessing.current_process().name
  input_queue.put(1)
  while not input_queue.empty():
    output_queue.put(input_queue.get() + 1)

def main():
  input_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
  output_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
  for i in range(8):
    input_queue.put(i)

  processes = []
  for i in range(2):
    process = multiprocessing.Process(name = str(i),
                                      target = do_work,
                                      args = (input_queue,
                                              output_queue), )
    processes.append(process)
    process.start()
  for process in processes:
    process.join()
  results = []
  while not output_queue.empty():
    results.append(output_queue.get())
  print len(results), results

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Sometimes result is - what looks good:

```
process 0
process 1
10 [2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 5, 8, 7, 2, 2]
```

But sometimes result is different like values 1 was not put at process start:

```
process 0
process 1
9 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2]
```

It looks that is not problem with print since it is done in main thread but with queues which not support interprocess locking. Can you suggests something?

Comment: That doesn't make the data structure thread-unsafe; it's asynchronous behavior, which is something I'd entirely expect to occur.

Comment: Makoto 10 value = 10 results with unknown order but not 9 results - see again I simplified presentation.

Comment: Where are you getting 10 from?

Comment: @Makoto `print len(results), results` once is 10 and once 9 - read question again. I have no idea why?

Comment: you need locks I think

Comment: @JoranBeasley Too much philosophy :) I think that locks will not help too much because it is not reason of this problem and can proof it - wrong idea.

Comment: I think the question ["How to make Python's multiprocessing Queue's .empty() method return the correct value? Or alternatives?
"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32395150/how-to-make-pythons-multiprocessing-queues-empty-method-return-the-correct) explains what's going on quite well.

Answer (score 3):

Here's your code slightly changed:

```py
# coding=utf-8
import multiprocessing

def do_work(input_queue, output_queue, lock):
  with lock:
    input_queue.put(1)
    print input_queue.empty(), input_queue.qsize()
    while not input_queue.empty():
      output_queue.put(input_queue.get() + 1)

def main():
  input_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
  output_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
  lock = multiprocessing.Lock()
  for i in range(8):
    input_queue.put(i)

  processes = []
  for i in range(2):
    process = multiprocessing.Process(name = str(i),
                                      target = do_work,
                                      args = (input_queue,
                                              output_queue, lock), )
    processes.append(process)
    process.start()
  for process in processes:
    process.join()
  results = []
  while not output_queue.empty():
    results.append(output_queue.get())
  print len(results), results

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Note that now the entire process is under a lock, so no race condition is possible, and it also prints both size of the input queue and whether it is empty or not. Now here's the output of one of the runs:

```
False 9
True 1
9 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2]
```

Note how the second process says that the queue is empty, but at the same time has one element. The reason for that is in the documentation:

> empty() Return True if the queue is empty, False otherwise. Because of
>   multithreading/multiprocessing semantics, this is **not reliable**.

To fix it, you can replace your condition `while not input_queue.empty()` with `while input_queue.qsize() > 0`. When you do that, you will see your code hanging. It makes sense, as you check the size of the queue first, and then try to pop it. Consider the following scenario: there's one element in the queue, both threads see that, and try to pop. One succeeds, another now tries to pop from an empty queue, and blocks. To fix that, try doing non-blocking pop, and retry if it fails:

```py
# coding=utf-8
import multiprocessing
import Queue

def do_work(input_queue, output_queue):
  input_queue.put(1)
  while input_queue.qsize() > 0:
    try:
      output_queue.put(input_queue.get(False) + 1)
    except Queue.Empty:
      pass

def main():
  input_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
  output_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
  for i in range(8):
    input_queue.put(i)

  processes = []
  for i in range(2):
    process = multiprocessing.Process(name = str(i),
                                      target = do_work,
                                      args = (input_queue,
                                              output_queue) )
    processes.append(process)
    process.start()
  for process in processes:
    process.join()
  results = []
  while True:
    try:
      results.append(output_queue.get(False))
    except Queue.Empty:
      break
  print len(results), results

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: You're right about locking, but this doesn't explain why the duplicate values appear in the queue.

Comment: @Makoto, because he inserts 1 three times, and then reinserts everything from the input queue to the output queue. Duplicates makes perfect sense

Comment: @makato It is wrong code It will give 10 or 9 results - tested!

Comment: Seems like this answer hits the nail on the head.  Not sure why I didn't notice that extra `put` call in the `do_work` method...

Comment: @Ishamael Lock will make code single thread so it is not solution (whole worker is lock it self). This code can give 9 or 10 results so same bug. Documentation says that empty is not reliable but what is reliable - in other place it not says that is not reliable - so hard to learn.

Comment: not reliable means it is not thread safe basically... apparently even worse than that (why even have that method?)

Comment: @Chameleon, that's my point, even when it is single threaded, it still doesn't work. Because empty is not reliable, which is stated in the docs. See my updated answer for a full solution.

Comment: I found some solution SimpleQueue whatever problem is not lock or empty but design for Queue - it should used in other way. Lock and Queue from multiprocessing is bad idea.

Comment: @Ishamael It works much better but still is not full parallel algorithm :) Why because `qsize` is local and not reliable as `empty` - each process will quit before all `puts()` will happen. This what we do is parallel recurrence - mix of both is brain boiling for many people :) Not give up try another solution you are near final solution. There is another method poison pills algorithm but will not work for recurrence without master process.

Comment: It is require global for condition if all processes will finish and there was not puts all should die if not they should work again with new puts. I will try to do it tomorrow since my energy become low and time to sleep.