# How to make Python's multiprocessing Queue's .empty() method return the correct value? Or alternatives?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

I have this snippet that uses the `Queue` class from the `multiprocess` module.  I am very confused that the `.empty()` method of an instance of `Queue` does not give me a correct value as i would expect.  This is my code:

```
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Queue, Lock

foo = Queue()
locker = Lock()

with locker:  # even with this, still True
    foo.put("bar")

print(foo.empty())  # True, obviously not
print(foo.empty())  # True
print(foo.empty())  # True
print(foo.qsize())  # 1L
print(foo.empty())  # True
```

However, if i use the `sleep` function from `time`, as in cause a chronological delay in the execution.  It works.

```
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Queue, Lock

foo = Queue()
locker = Lock()

foo.put("bar")

sleep(0.01)

print(foo.empty())  # False
print(foo.empty())  # False
print(foo.empty())  # False
print(foo.qsize())  # 1L
print(foo.empty())  # False
```

I know my alternative is the `.qsize() > 0` expression, but i am sure that i just doing this in a wrong way.

What am i doing wrong?

***EDIT***

I understand now that is it *unreliable*, thank you @Mathias Ettinger.  Any clean alternatives?  I need to know hot to reliably tell if my `Queue` is empty or not.

Comment: Nothing, neither `empty()`, `full()`, nor `qsize()` are [reliable](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.empty)

Comment: Haha, thank you for citing that.  Any alternatives?

Comment: Not sure what you want to do, but maybe a [JoinableQueue](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.JoinableQueue) is what you're looking for.

Comment: I think the one true interface to the queue is `put` and `get`; `empty` is for approximate statistics. In a processing node I'd use `get(block=False)` to immediately find out if the queue is empty _or_ get a piece of work.

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately, the Queue's complex implementation that means that `.empty()` and `.qsize()` check different things to make their judgments.  That means that they may disagree for a while, as you've seen.

Since `.qsize()` *is* supported on your platform (which is [not true everywhere](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.qsize)), you can re-implement the `.empty()` check in terms of `.qsize()`, and this will work for you:

```
# mp.Queue() is a function, not a class, so we need to find the true class
# to subclass
import multiprocessing.queues

class XQueue(multiprocessing.queues.Queue):
    def empty(self):
        try:
            return self.qsize() == 0
        except NotImplementedError:  # OS X -- see qsize() implementation
            return super(XQueue, self).empty()
```

Under the hood, the Queue `.put()` is a complex process:  the Queue places objects in a buffer and acquires an interprocess semaphore, while a hidden daemon thread is responsible for draining the buffer and serializing its contents to a pipe.  (Consumers then `.get()` by reading from this pipe and releasing the interprocess semaphore.)  So, that's why sleeping in your example works:  the daemon thread has enough time to move the object from in-memory buffer to I/O representation before you call `.empty()`.

As an aside, I find this behavior surprising:  a Queue in the very same internal state can give two different answers to the question, "do you have any elements enqueued?"  (`qsize` will say "yes", and `empty` "no".)

I think I understand how this came about.  Since not all platforms support `sem_getvalue()`, not all platforms can implement `qsize`, but `empty` can be reasonably implemented by just polling the FIFO.  I'd have expected `empty` to be implemented in terms of `qsize` on platforms that support the latter.

Comment: What is your comment about NotImplementedError? I checked documentation and there's nothing about it.

Comment: @User, if you follow the link in the second ¶ of my answer — the one about `qsize()` not being implemented on every platform — you'll read that that method _"... may raise `NotImplementedError` on Unix platforms like Mac OS X where `sem_getvalue()` is not implemented."_

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) says that `qsize` is unreliable, just like `empty` and `full`. Would you please link me to where you see that `qsize` is guarenteed to be correct immediately?

Comment: @MatthewMoisen, I've reconsidered this answer's phrasing — 5+ years later — and edited for clarity.  Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

As per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html), neither [`empty()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.empty), [`full()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.full), nor [`qsize()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.qsize) are reliable.

Alternatives includes:

- Reading the exact amount of items going through the `Queue`:

  ```
  AMT = 8
  for _ in range(AMT):
      queue.put('some stuff')

  for _ in range(AMT):
      print(queue.get())
  ```

  This is useful if you know beforehand how many items must be processed in total or how many will be processed by each thread.
- Reading items until a guardian appears:

  ```
  num_threads = 8
  guardian = 'STUFF DONE'

  while num_threads:
      item = queue.get()
      if item == guardian:
          num_threads -= 1
      else:
          process(item)
  ```

  This is helpful if every thread have a variable amount of work (and you don't know the total beforehand) to do but can determine when it’s done.

Comment: While this is all true, queue size methods are normally "unreliable" in the sense that the information may be stale as soon as it is fetched, rather than in the sense that they are inconsistent with actual queue state (which is what the OP noticed).  Also, using sentinels or _a priori_ knowledge of the number of items in a queue are fine techniques to know when you're done processing, but it's not clear that that's the OP's use case for `.empty()`